# XWalkView prevent navigation

Tags: java, android, crosswalk-project

I have a XWalkView in my andoid app that is used to display a single page, this page has a lot of popup ads and my goal is to prevent the XWalkView from navigating to other pages than the one I set it to.
In the UWP version of my app I wrote:

```
private void webView_NewWindowRequested(WebView sender, WebViewNewWindowRequestedEventArgs args)
{
    args.Handled = true;
}
```

and that solved that.
Is there any similar way to do this with XWalkView? Or any way at all?

Answer (score 0):

If you override `shouldOverrideUrlLoading`, you can return `true` to indicate that the request has been handled.

```
xwalkview.setResourceClient(new XWalkResourceClient(xwalkview) {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(XWalkView view, String url) {
        return !url.equals(MY_URL);
    }
});
```